# Problem showing items in a recyclerview Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to show all my posts stored in Firebase but it seems impossible to display the information into the recycler. I just manage to recover the data from firebase, because the size of the recyclerview is correct as it contents only two elements which the number of post I currently have in my firebase table. But nothing is show into the recycler. You can see my firebase in the attachment. The error I'm receiving is:

> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for imagen found on class com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.clases.Publicacion
> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for nombreUsuario found on class com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.clases.Publicacion
> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for comentario found on class com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.clases.Publicacion
> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for postUid found on class com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.clases.Publicacion
> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for imagen found on class com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.clases.Publicacion
> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for nombreUsuario found on class com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.clases.Publicacion
> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for comentario found on class com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.clases.Publicacion
> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for postUid found on class com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.clases.Publicacion

**Here you have my adapter**

```
package com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.adaptadores

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.R
import com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.clases.Publicacion
import com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.clases.Usuario
import com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.fragments.PerfilFragment
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener

//DESCRIPCION GENERAL. MUESTRA LOS USUARIOS. AL PULSAR EN EL BOTON SE SIGUE/NO SIGUE USUARIO/ ADEMAS AL PULSAR EN UN
//USUARIO RECYCLERVIEW SE ABRE EL USUARIO
class PublicacionAdaptador(private var context: Context, private var publicacionLista: List<Publicacion> ): RecyclerView.Adapter<PublicacionAdaptador.ViewHolder>() {
    //EMPEZAMOS RECUPERANDO LA IFNROMACIÓN DEL USUARIO ACTUAL

    private var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
    private lateinit var referenciaBD: DatabaseReference
    //CREAMOS UNA CLASE PARA MANIPULAR EL ADAPTADOR QUE DEVOLVERA UN OBJETO DEL ADAPTADOR
    class ViewHolder( itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var tvUsuario: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_usuario)
        var ivPerfil : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_perfil)
        var ivImagen : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_imagen)
        var ivbLike : ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivb_like)
        var ivbFavorita : ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivb_favorita)
        var ivbComentario : ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivb_comentar)
        var tvPublicacion: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_publicacion)
        var tvLikes: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_likes)
        var tvEscritor: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_escritor)
        var tvComentario: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_comentarios)
    }
    //CUANDO SE CREA EL ADAPTADOR NECESITA CARGARSE CON EL LAYOUT CORRESPONDIENTE AL USUARIO ESTO SE LOGRA
    //CON EL METODO onCreateViewHolder Y CARGAMOS EL LAYOUT DEL USUARIO
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view =LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.publicacion,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    //EL METODO onBindViewHolder MUESTRA POR PANTALLA LOS DATOS INDICADOS POR SU POSICION
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        firebaseUser =FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
        val publicacion = publicacionLista[position]
        holder.tvUsuario.text=firebaseUser.uid
        println(publicacion.propietarioPublicacion)
        Glide.with(context).load(publicacion.imagenPublicada).centerCrop().into(holder.ivPerfil)
        //holder.tvUsuario.text = publicacion.propietarioPublicacion.replaceFirstChar { it.uppercase()}
        holder.tvPublicacion.text = publicacion.contenidoPublicado


        
    }
    //GETITEMCOUNT SIMPLEMENTE CUENTA LOS ELEMENTOS QUE TIENEN EL RECYCLERVIEW
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return publicacionLista.size
    }

    //ETA FUNCION RECIBE EL UID DEL USUARIO CONTENIDO EN EL RECYCLERWIEW Y LOS BUSCARA TOMANDO COMO BASE
    //EL USUARIUO ATUTENTIFICADO. DE ESTA FORMA VEMOS SI EL USUARIO AUTENTIFICADO ESTA SIENDO SEGUIDO
    //SI ES ASI CAMBIARA  EL ESTADO DEL BOTON QUE A SIGUIENDO YA QUE POR DEFECTO ME DA LA OPCION DE SEGUIR
    private fun comprobarSiSigue( u_id:String, btn_seguir:Button)
    {
        //NOS POSICIONAMOS EN EL HIJO CORRESPONDIENTE A SIGUIENDO DEL USUARIO AUTENTIFICADO
        val followingRef = firebaseUser.uid.let{ it->
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Seguir").child(it)
                .child("Siguiendo")}
        //EN CASO DE QUE SE ENCUENTRE ALGUN VALOR. COSA QUE EVALUAMOS CON ADDAVALUEEVENTELISTENER CAMBIAMOS
        //RECUPERAMOS LOS DATOS DEL ESE VALOR CON SNAPSHOT Y SI EN ESE REGISTRO RECUPERADO LA UID QUE APARECE
        //ES LA QUE PASAMOS POR PARAMETRO QUIERE DECIR QUE EL USUARIO IDENTIFICADO YA ESTA SIGUIENDO AL USUARIO
        //DEL RECICLERVIEW ASI QUE CAMBIAMOS EL BOTN DE TEXTO Y COLOR.  SI NO ESTA LA UID ES QUE NO LO SEGUIMOS
        //ASI QUE CAMBIARIAMOS DE ESTADO OTRA VEZ EL BOTON
        followingRef.addValueEventListener(object :ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if(snapshot.child(u_id).exists()){
                    btn_seguir.setText("Siguiendo")
                    btn_seguir.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
                } else {
                    btn_seguir.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
                    btn_seguir.setText("Seguir")
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
    }

}
```

**This is my activity, which is in a fragment.**

```
package com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.R
import com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.adaptadores.PublicacionAdaptador
import com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.clases.Publicacion
import com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.clases.Usuario
import com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.databinding.FragmentInicioBinding
import com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.databinding.FragmentPublicacionBinding
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener


class InicioFragment : Fragment() {

    //LUEGO RECUPERARMOS EL FRAGMENTO EN BINDING

    private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    private var publicacionAdaptador: PublicacionAdaptador? = null
    private var mPublicacion: MutableList<Publicacion>? = null


    override fun onCreateView(

        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false)

        recyclerView = view?.findViewById(R.id.rec_publicacion)
        recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        // SE PUEDE PONER EN HORIZONTAL CON
        //    recyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
        mPublicacion = ArrayList()
        publicacionAdaptador = context?.let { PublicacionAdaptador(it, mPublicacion as ArrayList<Publicacion>) }
        recyclerView?.adapter = publicacionAdaptador
        mostrarPublicacionesCompletos()
        return view

    }
    private fun mostrarPublicacionesCompletos() {
        val usuarioActual  = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
        val uidActual = usuarioActual.uid
        val publicacionRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Publicaciones")
        Toast.makeText(context,"SE CONECTA A LA TABLA PUBLICACIONES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        publicacionRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
           //CARGAMOS TODOS LOS DATOS DE LA TABLA POSTS EN EL RECYCLERVIEW DATACHANGE SE ENCARGA DE CARGAR LOS DATOS
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                mPublicacion?.clear()
                //cada snapshop es un registro de una tabla
                for (snapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    val publicacion = snapshot.getValue(Publicacion::class.java)
                    //PARA QUE EL EDITAR PERFIL FUNCION SOLO DE EDITAR HE PREFERIDO
                    //MOSTRAR AL USUARIO AUTENTIFICADO TAMBIEN EN LA LISTA DE USUARIOS
                    //PARA QUE SE SIGA ASI MISMO. INSTRAGARM FUNCIONA IGUAL Y TE PUEDES SEGUIR A TI MISMO
                    //if (publicacion!!.publicacioonId == uidActual){
                        mPublicacion?.add(publicacion!!)
                    //}
                }
                //notify se ejcuta al final para guardar los cambios
                publicacionAdaptador?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                //VER QUE HACE
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**This is my class to store data**
It's just empty to store data

```
package com.example.tfg_red_social_v0.clases

class Publicacion(var publicacioonId: String ="", var propietarioPublicacion: String ="", var contenidoPublicado: String ="", var imagenPublicada: String="") {
}
```

**My xml layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#090909">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_usuario"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_perfil"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/camerab" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_imagen"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000000"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/galeria" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ivb_like"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/add" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ivb_favorita"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/add" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ivb_comentar"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/add" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_publicacion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:hint="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_likes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:hint="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_escritor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:hint="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_comentarios"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:hint="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've tried everything. Debugging. Searching for answering in other post but I can't find my mistake.
So please HELP!

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please also add the content of your `Publicacion` class.

Comment: I'll do next time. I managed to fix the problem thanks! ;)